# StackOverflow + [Certain] Images + Chrome = Malware Alert

Tags: support, status-completed, images, google-chrome, virus

Users [posting images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/notepad-tabs-to-spaces/455040#455040) with `freeimagehosting.net` are getting SO flagged.

Not sure where else to post this, but I thought I'd let the meta-mongers know. I obviously know it's not an issue personally but it could potentially freak people out.

[image: SO Flag]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have edited this post and uploaded the image to our image provider.  I have also blocked freeimagehosting.net via our blacklist for now to prevent any future issues.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the swift action.

Comment: Eek, there's 395 other posts that match `url:"*.freeimagehosting.net/*"`

Comment: Ugh, manually cleaning these up is not going to be very practical :(

Comment: Is this network wide? If not, it should be. (I've just checked Programmers and it's not on our blacklist)

Comment: Geoff this is still an issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160137/malware-warning-for-a-question

Comment: @Chris, it [should be network wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159675/can-we-please-block-malware-if-possible#comment462698_159689) as of 13 hours after you asked.

Comment: @Yannis That's actually a different URL (.com vs .net). I'll see about adding that to the blacklist. As for cleaning up all the posts that include those images goes... that'll probably take coordinated effort.

Comment: @AnnaLear If I remember correctly the actual url was .net, and it ended up as .com in the MSO question because the .net variant is blacklisted and can't be added to new posts (I tried posting a comment with the url, and the system barked at me). But, as always, the chances of me remembering something correctly are extremely low (I blame tequila).

Comment: @Yannis Ah, yeah, that makes sense. Well, that just leaves the second half of my comment then. :P