# Can we please block malware (if possible)

Tags: support, status-completed, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow + [Certain] Images + Chrome = Malware Alert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159512/stackoverflow-certain-images-chrome-malware-alert)

I just went here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9151/revisions

I got his up with this screen in Chrome:

[image]

How do we fix these types of issues?

I cannot go to the page in Chrome!

Comment: @hims056 but I do not want to "risk" it!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA if you don't want to risk malware, than disconnect from the internet

Comment: @SamIam but I live here.... I can't leave! I have hats that I need to take care of!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I destroyed the original revision that included freeimagehosting.net now that Shog9 took one for the team and replaced the image links.

We'll see about blacklisting freeimagehosting.net across the network (it's [already blacklisted on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159513/155160)).

Comment: Blacklisting network wide is done.