# Malware warning for a question

Tags: bug, specific-question, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow + [Certain] Images + Chrome = Malware Alert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159512/stackoverflow-certain-images-chrome-malware-alert)

I received malware warning on Chrome for this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455410/best-file-manager-for-developers

> Danger: Malware Ahead!
>   Google Chrome has blocked access to this page
>   on stackoverflow.com. Content from `www.` `freeimagehosting.com`, a known
>   malware distributor, has been inserted into this web page. Visiting
>   this page now is very likely to infect your Mac with malware.

Comment: I know the dupe is tagged as completed, but although the url can't be added to new posts there are 300+ old posts that haven't been cleaned up yet, and you've just stumbled upon one of them.

Comment: OK, I've uploaded all images to the dedicated image hosting, no more malware there. I fear that for old links this must be done manually..

Comment: Mac? Malware? What is this, Chrome?